# Having trouble detemining which query is actually faster

Tags: php, mysql

Please note that the database structure probably can't be changed without a lot of work due to the amount of users and data on it.

The "friends" table is basically like this:

```
> show create table `friends`
CREATE TABLE `friends` (
    `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `user1` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `user2` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `user1_2` (`user1`,`user2`),
    KEY `user1` (`user1`),
    KEY `user2` (`user2`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=747908
```

To fetch a user's friends, I have three options:

1. Individually select `user2` where `user1` equals the user's ID, and vice versa, then combine the results in PHP.
2. `SELECT IF(user1=@userid,user2,user1) FROM friends WHERE @userid IN (user1,user2)`
3. `SELECT user2 FROM friends WHERE user1=@userid`
   `UNION SELECT user1 FROM friends WHERE user2=@userid`

I tried timing options 2 and 3, and this is where I have a problem: The first time I run it, option 2 takes about 400ms whereas option 3 only takes less then 1ms. Every other time, however, opton 2 takes 0.6ms and option 2 takes 0.8ms.

What should I do? Which option is actually faster? The `EXPLAIN` queries return this:

```
id   select_type  table      type  possible_keys key     key_len ref   rows   Extra
1    SIMPLE       friends    index NULL          user1_2 8       NULL  386438 Using where; Using index

id   select_type  table      type  possible_keys key     key_len ref   rows   Extra
1    PRIMARY      friends    ref   user1,user1_2 user1_2 4       const 8      Using index
2    UNION        friends    ref   user2         user2   4       const 8
NULL UNION RESULT <union1,2> ALL   NULL          NULL    NULL    NULL  NULL
```

Comment: just make a script that runs each querry 1 million times and see which is faster...

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't really answer my question, since I run the query multiple times and get radically different times.

Comment: you mean you ran both querries 1 million times and query A was faster, and then did that again, and query B was faster?

Comment: What I mean is that the first query is slightly faster, but only if it's in the query cache from having been run once.

Comment: When your queries are not far apart option 1 is better. If you query only occasionally, then option 2 is better. But, if query 1 is only slightly faster, it probably isn't worth spending more time for evaluation.

Comment: I think the speed of the queries have neglectable speed differences, compared to the access time of the disk. It will be very hard measuring differences, due to caching of disk access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As usual when benchmarking, beware of caches.

Measure your `SELECT` queries using `SQL_NO_CACHE` clause (see the [`SELECT` syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html)).